# Display volley response as text in toast

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I'm using Volley library in my android app. I'm trying to create a registration function. Everything seems to work fine, I can register, however I cannot display any response from the PHP file as a toast on android. The toast does not even appear. Maybe I should show you my code first:

```
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
         try {
              JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
              String result = jsonResponse.getString(response);

              if(result == "Registered!") {
                    Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not register!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         };
     RegRequest regRequest = new RegRequest(username, password, email, listener);
     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegActivity.this);
     queue.add(regRequest);
```

Here's my regRequest class:

```
public class RegRequest extends StringRequest {

private static String regURL = "http://chicpiq.com/android/android_register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegRequest(String username, String password, String email, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super (Method.POST, regURL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("email", email);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
    }
}
```

Here's my PHP:

```
require "../database/database.php";

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['email']);
$joindate = date("y.m.d");

$encryptpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$register = mysqli_query($database, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, joindate) VALUES ('$username', '$encryptpass', '$email', '$joindate')");
mysqli_execute($register);
$response = "Registered!";

echo json_encode($response);
```

As I mentioned, I have no problem with registering, I can do that. My problem is that I want to change PHP code to check whether a user exists etc. and I want to display other messages. I can't seem to get to display response from PHP as a Toast. Has anyone got any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    try {

        js.put("username", username);
        js.put("password", password);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, constants.LOG_IN_URL, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        System.out.println("status" + response.get("status").toString().contains("success"));
                        if (response.get("status").toString().contains("success")) {

                           profileId.setText(response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("fname"));
                           userProfession.setText(response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("profession"));
                           userLocation.setText(response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("placeOfBirth"));
                            String url = "http://50.78.27.70:8080";
                            url =url.concat(response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("displayPicture"));
                            System.out.println("string" + response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("displayPicture"));
                            if(response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("displayPicture").equals("null"))
                            {
                                     profilePic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                            }
                            else{
                                Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).into(profilePic);
                                System.out.println("hello by default  2");
                            }




                        } else {
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TimeLine.this, "Wrong Id or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });


   Singleton.mInstance(TimeLine.this).addrequestqueue(request);
```